# Unable to boost the volume of YouTube videos as they stream using VLC

Tags: audio, video, vlc-media-player, youtube

It used to be that you could boost the volume of YouTube videos as they stream with VLC.  But at the moment, it doesn't seem to work. I used to open VLC, and do file..open network stream, and enter a YouTube URL.  Then I could raise the volume in VLC.. to maybe 200% or 400%.

But now, I get:

> Your input can't be opened: VLC is unable to open the MRL 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rdfs...'

I can't raise the volume of any YouTube videos through VLC, like I used to.

I suppose I could download a video and maybe use some method there, though that's not ideal; I'd rather do it as it streams, like I used to with VLC.

Is there still a way to do this in VLC?  If not, is there any other way to accomplish this?

Note- this is not a webapps question, because e.g. , as the [youtube](/questions/tagged/youtube) tag says, go to webapps unless you require heavy integration with a desktop application. And that's what I'm talking about here.

Answer (score 1):

Modify URL of video you want to play/amplify in VLC such way it will be forced to play as HTML5 then you can still use VLC on streams.

If link to your video for example is `htty://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abcd` convert it to : `htty://www.youtube.com/embed/abcd?html5=1` and use this link in VLC

Comment: `htty` ? ? ?   (dang comment character requirement)

Comment: @Twisty Th-h!!! it on purpose - to avoid indexation :)